# Scroll bar set on Bar chart in android using achartengine

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

In my project i have to display the bar chart for 30 days with daily net amount. While view of bar chart activity the X-axis labels were collapsed and **all are** **shown** without any spacing. While i clicked the zoom buttons that time the views are expanded and we can see the bar with their corresponding x-axis labels. I need to show the bar chart on expanded view on the time of activity started.

### Coding for display the Bar Chart:

```
     XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        renderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        renderer. setLegendTextSize(15);
//     renderer.setInScroll(true);
        //renderer.setMargins(new int[]{10,10,10,0});
        int length = colors.length;
        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
          SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
          r.setColor(colors[j]);
          renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        }
        if(flag==1)
     renderer.setChartTitle("Monthly Basis");
        if(flag==0)
             renderer.setChartTitle("Weekly Basis");
        if(flag==2)
             renderer.setChartTitle("Yearly Basis");
    renderer.setXTitle("Date");
    renderer.setYTitle("NetAmount");

    renderer.setXAxisMin(0);

    //renderer
    renderer.setYAxisMin(100);
   // renderer.setYAxisMax(35000);
    renderer.setAxesColor(Color.GRAY);
    renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.LTGRAY);
          renderer.setXLabels(0);
          //renderer.setYLabels(31);
            renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
            renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
            renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
          if(flag==0 || flag==1)
          {
             for(int axis=1;axis<=31;axis++)
            {
                String d;
                d=String.valueOf(axis);
                renderer.addTextLabel(axis,d);

            }
          }
          else
          {
              renderer.setXAxisMin(2005);
              for(int axis=2005;axis<=2011;axis++)
                {
                    String d;
                    d=String.valueOf(axis);
                    renderer.addTextLabel(axis,d);

                }

             // renderer.setXLabels(4);
          }
             //renderer.setPanEnabled(false,false);
             //renderer.setZoomEnabled(false,false);
           // renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { 0, 32, -10, 40 });
          // renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { 0, 32, -10, 40 });
            renderer.setZoomRate(3.0f);
            renderer.setBarSpacing(0.25);
            //renderer.set(new  double[] {0,30,100,35000});
            //Intent in;

            List<double[]> xvalues = new ArrayList<double[]>();

            int count=1,j=0;
           if(flag==0 || flag==1)
           {
            double xdata[]=new double[31];
            while(count<32)
            {

            xdata[j]=count;
            count++;
            j++;

            }
            xvalues.add(xdata);
           }
           if(flag==2)
           {
            double xdata[]=new double[7];
            count=2005;
            while(j<7)
            {

            xdata[j]=count;
            count++;
            j++;

            }
            xvalues.add(xdata);
           }


          //  return ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, buildBarDataset(titles,xvalues,values), renderer,
            //    Type.DEFAULT);
            mchart=ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context,buildBarDataset(titles,xvalues,values), renderer, Type.STACKED);
            //LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
            layout.addView(mchart);
            mchart.repaint();

            //startActivity(in);

  }


     protected XYMultipleSeriesDataset buildBarDataset(String[] titles, List<double[]> xvalues, List<double[]> values) {
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
     int length = titles.length;
     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    //CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(titles[i]);
XYSeries series = new XYSeries(titles[i]);
double[] v = values.get(i);
double[]x=xvalues.get(i);

int seriesLength = v.length;
    for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
if(v[k]==0)
{
v[k]=MathHelper.NULL_VALUE;
}
else
{
     series.add(x[k],v[k]);
}
      //Log.i("Invent","X Axis"+x[k]);
//series.add(xdata[k],v[k]);
     }
     dataset.addSeries(series);
    for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
if(v[k]==MathHelper.NULL_VALUE)
{
v[k]=0;
}
     }
    }
   return dataset;
       }


}
```

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you describe, could you add a picture or try to write in another way? What do you mean with congested? Above each other? Also some short code where you add the values to the bar chart could help.

Comment: Thank you for Reply larlin. Sorry for that issue. For your understanding i added my code now. Please verify it. In this coding i had set the x-axis value as 31 and their corresponding y-axis values. The problem occur on Bar chart View set the x-axis labels  were collapsed with another. The View is form of 31 entries are appeared within on view screen at a time. So i want to set the scroll bar to view the 30 days value with accurate spacing

Comment: larlin sir. Can u understand it? Please help me . It's urgent.

Comment: If anyone known answer for it, Please share .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I'm not 100% sure but here goes a shot.</strike>

First you seems to use a deprecated method addTextLabel when current suggested is addXTextLabel.

Secondly you set setXLabels(0); with seems odd as you are going to have more then 0 XLabels also unsure how this will work with the depreciated method used.

Thirdly I think the X value in the addTextLabel are actually, a position not a bar index.

I'm no expert in neither aChartEngine or have time to test your code just now. I will do some testing later tonight and edit this answer with the result. If no other answer helps you.

(edit)

After testing your code I get this result:

[image: labels after inserting]

This is a problem that is solvable in 3 ways:

- Reduce the number of labels, e.g. only printing ever other.
- Use a smaller font size for the labels, I think this will be hard in this case, as I think the readability will suffer greatly.
- Try to make the axis longer by e.g. removing the labels on the other axis. I guess you want to show labels for the amount there so not useful here.

I have made a very simple and naive implementation of skipping ever other as I think that is the most useful solution here.

```
for(int axis=1;axis<=31;axis++)
{
  if(axis%2 == 1){
    String d;
    d=String.valueOf(axis);
    renderer.addTextLabel(axis,d);
  }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Hope this helps!

(edit again)

New understanding of the question the above is still correct but here is the answer to the question as I under stand it now.

To get pan to work you need to have pan enabled (already done in this question) and then set xAxisMax to something less then the length of the dataset. In this example it's easiest to just set it to e.g. 15f this is done like this:

```
renderer.setXAxisMax(15.0f);
```

Hope this is what you wanted.

Comment: Please don't accept a answer until you know it works. If the answer is a bit unclear (as mine is above) please also state what you did from the answer that helped. If you just generally feel helped by a answer please just upvote the answer, and wait with accept until you know it worked.

Comment: Sorry sir, I want to make 30 days and their labels display on x-axis without omitting anyone. Is it chance to display via setting up scroll bar on this?

Comment: Sorry missed that part, to make the bar only be a few data points long change the size of the axis by: renderer.setXAxisMax(15.0f); This will show the first 15 datapoints. Updated my answer.

Comment: renderer.setXAxisMax(15.0f) is worked well. Thank you so much larlin.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your very confusing question correctly, you need to use [`setBarSpacing()`](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html#setBarSpacing%28double%29).

Comment: Thank you for Reply Dheeraj. I had also added setBarSpacing() in my coding.

Comment: Sorry sir. I cannot add the screenshot here. Websites blocked as a spam because of i have less reputations.